# Angular NPM package using after publishing

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I build an npm package as a test to see how it works. So far it worked, I could build it (--prod) and publish it to a registry. Just one question, if I want to use it in a different project I can include the Module of my npm package which is published and it will be shown in my project.

My Module consists of a few components (ts and HTML) how do I do that if I only want to use one component? So install everything but only use one of them through the selector? For example Angular packages like routing you can do something like this
"" this is what I want to do too.

My module.ts of npm package

```
   import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ShowTitleComponent } from './show-title/show-title.component';
import { MypageComponent } from './mypage/mypage.component';
import { MyCounterComponent } from './my-counter/my-counter.component';
import { MyTitleComponent } from './my-title/my-title.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: MypageComponent}
    ]),
  ],
  declarations: [ShowTitleComponent, MypageComponent, MyCounterComponent, MyTitleComponent]
})
export class MyuiModule {}
```

And say I want to install everything but only use ShowtitleComponent, how do I do this? If I import my module in new project everything is shown.